# Data annotation - asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I m new to MVC. I have make a model **LoginModel**

```
{
    [Required (ErrorMessage="Username is required field.")]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessage="Password is required field.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and design a Form for it with **id = "CustomLogin"** and its **action="User/Validate"**
and **Validate** action returns **JsonResult**

In **web.config,**

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

In my **_Layout.cshtml,**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Now, if i directly click on "Submit" button of **form (CustomLogin)**, so it prevents me to jump **User/Validate** that is right..

But in external Javascript say **mycode.js**, I have also written

```
 $(document).ready(
     function()
     {
          $('#CustomLogin').submit(
            function(e)
            {
               alert ('i executed.');
               //suppose, here i wrote JSON call, it will also be executed
            });
     });
```

It is also executed. So is it OK..??

My thinking is if I **click on submit button, without passing any value,**

Unobstrusive javascript prevents jumping control over my post request "User/Validate",

> then it should also prevent my **submit** event. To solve this, I have used  **$("form").valid()** in my submit event handler.

like this,

```
  if ( $("#CustomLogin").valid() ) 
  {
       alert('I executed.');
  }
```

I think Unobstrusive javascript makes form state : invalid or valid...

**> BUT, my question is if I need to use $("form").valid(), then WHAT IS

> USE OF Unobstrusive javascript for validation...???? **

So is this OK.. or i m doing in wrong manner

Answer (score 0):

Because your model is invalid, doesn't necessarily mean you don't want to communicate with the server. It just means you don't want to submit that model.